# upcoming .net version and cross platform

Tags: c#, .net, mono, cross-platform

Microsoft [announced](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/11/12/announcing-net-2015-preview-a-new-era-for-net.aspx) in November 2014 that the new .net framework will support Linux/Mac. I'm little confused, so I've few questions about it ?

- Will I able to develop cross platform application using C# and
  VisualStudio ?
- If yes, is new .net framework going to be same as Mono
  ?

Answer (score 0):

Acording to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2014/11/12/opening-up-visual-studio-and-net-to-every-developer-any-application-net-server-core-open-source-and-cross-platform-visual-studio-community-2013-and-preview-of-visual-studio-2015-and-net-2015.aspx):

> •Over the coming months, we will be open sourcing the full server-side .NET Core stack, from ASP.NET 5 down to the Core Runtime and Framework, and the open source .NET will be expanded to run on Linux and Mac OS X in addition to Windows.

Also, from [here](http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-to-open-source-more-of-net-and-bring-it-to-linux-mac-os-x/):

> Microsoft is not planning to open source the client side .NET stack, which means it won't be open sourcing libraries specific to the client such as Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) and Windows Forms